# jquery onChange event is firing more than once on my jquery mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JS code using jquery onChange funtion is firing multiple times when it seem like it should only fire once.

I have four jquery mobile radio buttons and when you click on one, the value of the radio button that was clicked on, gets evaluated and then I rewrite the page URL to remove/add the correct url string and then submit this via AJAX via my loadResults(url) function and then the updated content gets displayed.

This seems to work as expected the first time one of the radio buttons is clicked on but after that it seems that loadResults gets called repeatedly and I can't figure out why.

Here is my html code for the radio buttons:

```
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="proptype">
          <!--{if ($searchCriteria.openHouseSearch != 1 || $searchCriteria.latest != 1 )}-->              
                <input type="radio" name="propStatus" id="propStatus-active" value="activelistings" checked>
          <!--{else}-->
                <input type="radio" name="propStatus" id="propStatus-active" value="activelistings">
          <!--{/if}-->
          <label for="propStatus-active">Active Listings</label>      

          <!--{if ($searchCriteria.latest == 1 || $searchCriteria.propStatus == latest) }-->
                <input type="radio" name="propStatus" id="propStatus-new" value="latest" checked>
          <!--{else}-->
                <input type="radio" name="propStatus" id="propStatus-new" value="latest">
          <!--{/if}-->
          <label for="propStatus-new">New Listings</label>

          <!--{if $searchCriteria.openHouseSearch == 1}-->
                <input type="radio" name="propStatus" id="propStatus-openHouse" value="openHouseSearch" checked>
          <!--{else}-->
                <input type="radio" name="propStatus" id="propStatus-openHouse" value="openHouseSearch">
          <!--{/if}-->
            <label for="propStatus-openHouse">Open Houses</label>

          <!--{if $searchCriteria.areaSearch == 1}-->
                <input type="radio" name="propStatus" id="propStatus-areaSearch" value="areaSearch" onchecked>
          <!--{else}-->
                <input type="radio" name="propStatus" id="propStatus-areaSearch" value="areaSearch">
          <!--{/if}-->
            <label for="propStatus-areaSearch">Area Search</label>

        </fieldset>
```

Here is my jquery javascript code:

$j(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#resultspage', function(){

```
//alert('this is fired'); 

    $j('#proptype input[type=radio]').change(function(e){
        //alert(url);
        //alert ('RADIOBUTTON VALUE IS: ' +$j(this).val() )
                var url = window.location.href; 
                if ($j(this).val() == "latest") { // New Listings
                    //alert('This is a new listings search');
                    document.getElementById('areainformation').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('resultsContents').style.display = 'block';
                    url = url.replace(/&activelistings=1/g,'');
                    url = url.replace(/&openHouseSearch=1/g,'');
                    url = url.replace(/&page=[0-9]+/g,'');
                    url = url.replace(/&areaSearch=1/g,'');
                    url += "&latest=1";
                    //alert('latest is value: ' +url);
                    loadResults(url);
                } else if ($j(this).val() == "openHouseSearch") { // Open Houses
                    // WHY IS THIS FIRED MULTIPLE TIMES AFTER YOU DO A NEW LISTINGS SEARCH AND THEN CHOOSE AN OPENHOUSE SEARCH??
                    //alert('This is an openHouse search');
                    document.getElementById('areainformation').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('resultsContents').style.display = 'block';
                    url = url.replace(/&activelistings=1/g,'');
                    url = url.replace(/&latest=1/g,'');
                    url = url.replace(/&propStatus=latest/g,'');
                    url = url.replace(/&page=[0-9]+/g,'');
                    url = url.replace(/&areaSearch=1/g,'');
                    url += "&openHouseSearch=1";
                    //alert('openHouseSearch is value: ' +url);
                    loadResults(url);
                } else { // All Active Listings or Area Search
                    if ($j(this).val() == "areaSearch") { // Area Search
                        //$j('#areainformation').style.display = 'block';
                        //$j('#resultsContents').style.display = 'none';
                        //alert('This is an area search');
                        document.getElementById('areainformation').style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById('resultsContents').style.display = 'none';
                    } else {
                        //alert('This is an all active listings search');
                        document.getElementById('areainformation').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('resultsContents').style.display = 'block';
                        url = url.replace(/&openHouseSearch=1/g,'');
                        url = url.replace(/&latest=1/g,'');
                        url = url.replace(/&propStatus=latest/g,'');
                        url = url.replace(/&page=[0-9]+/g,'');
                        url = url.replace(/&areaSearch=1/g,'');
                        url += "&activelistings=1";
                        //alert('doing activelisting: ' +url);
                        loadResults(url);
                    }
                }
      });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you're getting change events from the other radio buttons.  With a radio button group, you're setting one value and clearing the currently selected one (which doesn't happen the first time because nothing is already selected).

You might be able to fix the behavior by cancelling the event.